# How to plot circles on path using React D3 for tooltip for large dataset fast

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs, dataset

Chart loads fine without tooltip. Calling tooltip (plotting circle over path - about 24000 points) component totally slows. Spinner hangs for about 12 seconds before rendering. Following is the loop that is inside render that slows. Any ideas on how to render this component later ( in background) after rendering line chart first.
Could there be a different approach for solving this problem ?

```
    tooltip = data.points.map((series, id) => {
  return series.map((d,i) =>{
  return (
    <circle
       r={this.state.radius}
       cx={cx(d)}
       cy={cy(d)}
       >
       <cover
        x={tex}
        y={fab}
       />
     </circle>
  );
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution in this [enter link description here](https://bocoup.com/weblog/d3js-and-canvas)

Using D3 with Canvas for plotting large graph is the way to go. I was using SVG to render the graph as well.